# How do i get a transparent background using imsave in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this code that runs through several files and creates a png of each file.  Most of the image is actually blank space.  I would like for this space to be transparent (for it is to be used in an overlay in Google Earth)

Here is my current code.  And it produces the image that i want, however the background/blank space is blue instead of transparent.  How can i make the background transparent??

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ColorTable = plt.cm.jet
NPYFiles = [x for x in os.listdir('{0}/files/'.format(OutputDir)) if x.endswith('.npy')]
for i,ZiFile in enumerate(NPYFiles):
    print('\t\t{0}% Complete...'.format('{0:.2f}'.format(100*(1+i)/len(NPYFiles))), end='\r')
    zi = np.load('{0}/files/{1}'.format(OutputDir, ZiFile))
    plt.imsave(OutputDir + '/files/' + ZiFile.split('.npy')[0], zi, origin='lower', vmin=ziMin, vmax=ziMax, cmap=ColorTable)
```

Comment: `imsave` does not produce any "background". It saves exactly the image data you provide, i.e. everything that is blue *is* actually part of the image. Therefore you need to change the colormap, to map what you consider as background to a transparent color.